# I have a number of sagging drawers due to broken rear brackets on sliding drawers. Can anyone help me find replacement brackets (pictured below)?

Tags: repair

I have reversed some that have broken on the bottom to the other side, which is a temporary fix.  These brackets are not flush with the back wood panel but fit over a 1" x 1/2" strip.

Any help with locating these would be awesome.  I need at least 4 sets.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: There's room to glue a piece of wood between the metal rail and the left side. You could then screw the rail to that piece of wood.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find metal replacement boots from the manufacturer but it might be easiest to add some blocking as suggested by RedGrittyBrick. If that's the path you take I would suggest creating a vertical standard as opposed to horizontal applied blocking because it bears the weight of the drawer down into the floor of the cabinet instead of relying on the side wall (which may be very thin and week if the cabinets are of low quality) for structural integrity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if you offered me the plastic brackets to install so I could *cheat and run away*, I might encourage you to use something METAL that you won't call me back for, breaking again. For these types or repairs I don't bother to find the  original plastic hardware. Any hardware store will have what will fix this for the life of the cabinet: ([amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HR4XY1E))

[image]

Attach them with small nuts and bolts to the slide, through drilled holes you have *very* carefully measured for to aline it to the correct overall length. Use panheads and insert them going to the outside, so as to not interfere with the drawer.

---

"[Drawer slide brackets](https://www.google.com/search?q=drawer%20slide%20hack%20repair&client=firefox-a&hs=HTg&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&biw=1280&bih=890&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nxlxVLCqCe2IsQT39YLADw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&q=%22drawer%20slide%20brackets%22&imgdii=_)":

[image][rvadenver.com](https://www.rvadenver.com/latches_and_fasteners.htm)

---

People in the same *exact* boat, along with a product recommendation: [swisco.com/discussions/Rear-socket-replacement-for-kitchen-cabinet](http://www.swisco.com/discussions/Rear-socket-replacement-for-kitchen-cabinet-77-10759)

Comment: Do you have a picture or diagram to visually show your recommendation?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I don't own any IKEA stuff [smirk], I'll try to remember to grab a photo of my latest installment the next time I'm over there.